# invalid heap error when pushing self-defined data into the priority_queue

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

I am now trying to solve a problem that requires me to find the top `k` frequent numbers in a `2`-dimensional matrix.

I define a structure `numCount` that has two fields: `number` to store the number and `count` to store its times of appearances. Then I visit each number in the matrix, if its `numCount` structure already exists in a max-heap (sorted by `count`), I just increase its `count` by `1`; otherwise I create a new `numCount` object and push it into the heap. Note that in order to efficiently obtain the `numCount` object corresponding to a number, I keep an `unordered_map` for their correspondences.

The main logic of my idea is shown in the following code. However, the `push` operation gives `invalid heap` error after adding some `numCount` objects to the heap.

```
struct numCount {
    int number;
    int count;
    numCount(int num) : number(num), count(1) {}
};

struct compare {
    bool operator() (numCount*& lhs, numCount*& rhs) {
        return lhs -> count > rhs -> count;
    }
};

vector<int> kPopular(vector<vector<int> >& nums, int k) {
    int m = nums.size(), n = nums[0].size();
    priority_queue<numCount*, vector<numCount*>, compare> pq;
    unordered_map<int, numCount*> mp;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (mp.find(nums[i][j]) != mp.end())
                mp[nums[i][j]] -> count++;
            else {
                numCount* ncnt = new numCount(nums[i][j]);
                pq.push(ncnt); // This line gives the "invalid heap" error.
                mp[nums[i][j]] = ncnt;               
            }
        }
    }
    vector<int> popular(k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        popular[i] = pq.top() -> number;
        pq.pop();
    }
    return popular;
}
```

I test this code on the following matrix:

```
nums = [[1, 1, 2],
        [2, 2, 3]
        [1, 2, 3]]
```

Then it throws the `invalid heap` error when trying to add the `numCount` object corresponding to the first `3` at `nums[1][2]`.

How can I fix this bug?

**Updated**: After taking the suggestions of @JSF, I have updated my code as follows.

```
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs) const {
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
};

vector<int> kPopular(vector<vector<int> >& nums, int k) {
    int m = nums.size(), n = nums[0].size();
    unordered_map<int, int> counts;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            counts[nums[i][j]]++;
    set<pair<int, int>, compare> st;
    for (auto pr : counts) {
        st.insert(pr);
        if ((int)st.size() > k)
            st.erase(st.begin());
    }
    vector<int> popular(k);
    set<pair<int, int>, compare>::iterator itr = st.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        popular[i] = (*itr).first;
        itr = st.erase(itr);
    }
    return popular;
}
```

Comment: I know nothing about C++ but `pq` probably doesn't like that you're modifying how elements compare (via modifying `count`) after they've been added to the queue.

Comment: Hi, @melpomene Ok, I now would like to give a try of `set`.

Comment: this code would be much simplified to store objects by value, instead of using pointers

Comment: Hi, @MattMcNabb Well, I use pointers because I need to guarantee that the `numCount` object in the unordered_map `mp` and the priority_queue `pq` is the same one. And I cannot figure out how to do this by storing values. Could you please describe your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the key of an existing entry in a priority queue is both the cause of your problem and a giant mess to accomplish correctly.  For your purposes, there is no need to do that at all.
Keeping the priority queue incrementally serves no purpose that you have identified and makes your algorithm inefficient, as well as creating the above problem that would be hard to correct.

Instead, you should first read all the data and compute all the counts.  A map from number to count would be much simpler for that stage as well as more efficient than your extra level of indirection.

Once you have computed all the counts, you can then find the k largest.  A priority queue is one possibility for a good tool for finding the k largest, but efficient use of that queue would involve reversing the sense of the k.  Build a queue that will hold up to k items and always identify the smallest (not largest of those k items).  Insert the first k `number,count` pairs in the Q, then for each of the rest, compare it to the smallest in the Q and replace the smallest in the Q with the new pair if the new one is larger than the old smallest.

If you had a good reason to keep an incremental Q while computing the counts, that reason was not evident in your post and you should make that clear.  It is not impossible to work with a priority queue in which changing keys of existing items is supported.  I need that in many places in my own work and chose to code my own priority queue (rather than use std) to make that aspect easier.  Coding your own is not that hard, but probably there is also a way to use the std version.  But before going into that kind of complexity, explain why the problem requires it.

Comment: Hi, @JSF Your idea is really nice. I have updated my code and post it after the above question. In fact, I do not have a reason to keep the queue incremental and just inadvertently do this :-) Moreover, I now use `set` instead of `priority_queue`.